# Why does the non-euclidean distance between the lines $x=0$, $x=1$ approach $0$ as $y \to \infty$?

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Why does the non-euclidean distance between the lines $x=0$, $x=1$ approach $0$ as $y \to \infty$?

Please see http://books.google.ca/books?isbn=0387290524 on pg 191 for more information.

My thoughts: find the noneuclidean line that contains both points $iy$ and $iy+1$. Then transform to $y$-axis by Möbius transformation $f$. Then as $y$ goes to $\infty$, $f(iy)=f(iy+1) = i$.

I just don't know how to calculate the limit of $f(iy)$ as $y\to\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question body and the book itself say $y \to \infty$, so I'll assume that the title is wrong.

Your idea is a good one. We want to find the limit of $d(iy, iy + 1)$ as $y \to \infty$. We know that the non-Euclidean distance is invariant under dilations. Apply the dilation $z \mapsto \dfrac{1}{y} z$ to get:

$$
d(iy, iy + 1) = d\left(i, i + \frac{1}{y}\right)
$$

The distance between $i$ and $i + 1/y$ goes to $0$ as $y \to \infty$. The desired result follows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pick the non-euclidean line "semi-circle" with center at $x = 1/2$ so that the points $iy$ and $1+iy$ lie on the semi-circle with radius $\sqrt{1/4 + y^2}$. So the dilation must be by $k=1/\sqrt{1/4+y^2}$ to get a unit circle (and of course shift the center to origin $(0,0)$ with translation $z-1/2$). Then $d(iy, 1+iy)$ after dilation & translation is $d((-1/2+iy)/\sqrt{1/4+y^2},(1/2+iy)/\sqrt{1/4+y^2})$ which in the limit is $d(i,i)=0$ as $y\to\infty$

Comment: Justen,Thanks for formatting the expressions. Looks much better.